# Java - How to work with a large certificate revocation list (CRL) file?

Tags: java, certificate

I have found numerous examples on the web on how to load a CRL file by using the CertificateFactory's generateCRL(InputStream) method.

The file I have is really large, and I don't want to load all into mem.

I have been unable to find an approach that allows me to search the file without loading it into mem.

Ideas?  Experience?

Here's some more research.  I looked at the source for this and it claims that it will read one-at-a-time if the InputStream type is "mark" capable.
I switched to use BufferedInputStream (supports marks) and it still all gets read in at once.  Looked at the X509Factory src code some more, and it may be the way the file is created and all of the revokes are in the first data block.

Comment: CertificateFactory with a markable stream can read one CRL from a file without reading the _rest_ of the file. This allows you to handle a file that contains a cert and a CRL or a CRL and a cert, or several certs and a CRL etc, or several certs and several CRLs etc, or just multiple CRLs. It does not allow you to handle only part of _one_ CRL. Is your file large because it contains many small CRLs and/or other data, or is it large because it contains one large CRL?

Comment: I believe it is the latter (one large CRL) based on my investigations.